# npm install, missing node_modules folder

Tags: git, node.js, github, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to install a mini-application inside of another application using npm and the mini-application has all dependencies checked in.  However, when I run npm install from the root of the containing application:

`npm install git+ssh://git@github.com/blah/shmah`

It doesn't install the `node_modules` folder

Also, it gives me a bunch of `npm WARN excluding symbolic link...` warnings.

```
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/.bin/buster -> ../buster/bin/buster
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/.bin/buster-autotest -> ../buster/bin/buster-autotest
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/.bin/buster-server -> ../buster/bin/buster-   server
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/.bin/buster-static -> ../buster/bin/buster-static
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/.bin/buster-test -> ../buster/bin/buster-test
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/.bin/grunt-modernizr -> ../grunt-modernizr/bin/grunt-modernizr
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/.bin/grunt-preprocess -> ../grunt-preprocess/bin/grunt-preprocess
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/.bin/grunt-symlink -> ../grunt-symlink/bin/grunt-symlink
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/.bin/hulk -> ../hogan.js/bin/hulk
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/buster/node_modules/.bin/buster-static -> ../buster-static/bin/buster-static
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/buster/node_modules/.bin/lodash -> ../lodash/build.js
npm WARN excluding symbolic link node_modules/buster/node_modules/buster-server-cli/node_modules/phantom-proxy/node_modules/.bin/express -> ../express/bin/express
```

...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out (?)

If I add a [bundledDependencies](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#bundledDependencies) array to my package.json, this problem goes away.  I just need to be sure that every dependency that's being checked into the repo is included in the bundledDependencies array.

I would have figured this was a more common use case, however, so the fact that I had such  a hard time finding anything on the subject makes me think I might be going about it the wrong way.  More specifically, we are currently checking in these dependencies to avoid any issues when deploying to production, a better solution might be for us to switch to not checking the dependencies in and instead using [npm shrinkwrap](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html)